# How can I reduce the size of my docker image?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, docker

I have this dockerfile to compile and run an api which is rather small created in Netfw461.

So I researched to get the desired output, so here it is. I used multistage to reduce the size in theory of the image, yet I tried several things and still cannot reduce from 5.5gb.

Here is my dockerfile (with obscured values for privacy)

```
# escape=`

##########################
# STAGE: build
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS app-build

# copy the needed files to build
COPY <solution files> into /appsrc/src

# build the package, and it will generate output to \appsrc\out folder (location in pubxml file)
RUN ["msbuild", "<mycsproj in sln>", "/p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=<publishfile>"]

##########################
# STAGE: configure OS to have IIS and ASPNET (try not to modify this)
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2 as aspnet-run

COPY --from=app-build C:\\appsrc\\out C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\apprun

RUN New-WebAppPool -Name <pool>
    New-WebApplication -Site 'Default Web Site' -Name <web> -PhysicalPath 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apprun' -ApplicationPool <pool>;

# END
##########################
```

In theory the aspnet image already has the entrypoint and I run the image and it works correctly.

The issue that I'm struggling with is the size of the image, which remains in 5.5gb. I suspect that is the size of the aspnet image I'm using as basis, but then how can I reduce it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm only new to Docker, but the image microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2 is 7GB in itself and if you're creating an image based on that then would your image not be bigger?

Comment: Yup indeed. That is what I suspect. I was also asking if there would be another way :)

Comment: There is .net core!!! Tiny image sizes in comparison

Comment: Yup, definitely that would be great if I could migrate all my solutions...